# changing variables inside procedures

Tags: python, variables, procedures

I have created a variable inside the Start() procedure but it doesn't seem remember the variable outside of the procedure. Is there a way of getting python to remember the variable outside of the Start() procedure? My code is as follows:

```
def Start():
    password = raw_input("Enter A Password With 7 Or More Characters: ")
    passwordLength = len(password)
    if passwordLength<7:
        print "Your entered a password with less than 7 characters. Enter a longer password."
        Start()
    else:
        reEnter = raw_input("Re-enter your password: ")
        if reEnter<>password:
        print "Your passwords did not match, please try again."
        Start()
        if reEnter==password:
        print "Your password has been saved."


Start()

print password
print passwordLength
```

Comment: global password, passwordLength

Answer (score 1):

You can return your variable at the end of your function.

```
def Start():
    password = input("Enter A Password With 7 Or More Characters: ")
    passwordLength = len(password)
    if passwordLength<7:
        print("Your entered a password with less than 7 characters. Enter a longer password.")
        return Start()
    else:
        reEnter = input("Re-enter your password: ")
        if not reEnter == password:
            print("Your passwords did not match, please try again.")
            return Start()
        else:
            print("Your password has been saved.")
            return password, passwordLength

savedPass, passLength = Start()

print(savedPass)
print(passLength)
```

EDIT: Edited style (thanks @jrennie) and recursive calls. (thanks @bgporter)

Comment: Style nits: If you use underscores to separate words, please don't capitalize. Also, if you are treating `print` like a function (3.x style), there shouldn't be a space between `print` and the left paren.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. Changed variables to mixed case since it is much suitable to OPs style.

Comment: In the recursive calls to `Start()` in both the `if` and `else` branches, you need to return the tuple returned from those calls for things to work correctly -- `return Start()`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that password and passwordLength are global variables. For this, you would use the global keyword, by simply at the beginning of your Start() defining them like so:

```
def Start():
    global password
    global passwordLength

    password = raw_input("Enter A Password With 7 Or More Characters: ")
    passwordLength = len(password)
    if passwordLength<7:
        print "Your entered a password with less than 7 characters. Enter a longer password."
        Start()
    else:
        reEnter = raw_input("Re-enter your password: ")
        if reEnter<>password:
            print "Your passwords did not match, please try again."
            Start()
        if reEnter==password:
            print "Your password has been saved."
```

However, globals are often frowned upon in python. If possible try and use return to print your output, but for most cases global is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
def Start():
    global password
    global passwordLength
    ....
```

Comment: That or return the value you want, and assign the return value to a variable in the caller.